# asio's tcp socket::async_wait() and closing the socket after that

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

When on open socket I call [async_read()](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_read.html)/[read()](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read.html) and the peer closes the socket after that - I will get `eof` error in the handlers, but with [async_wait()](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_wait.html)/[wait()](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/wait.html) this does not happen, the handler called with no error, ie error_code == 0

Should it be so?

Example:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
    const std::uint16_t port = 44550;

    boost::asio::io_context ioctx;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep{boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(ip), port};
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acc{ioctx, ep, true};
    acc.async_accept(
        [](const boost::system::error_code &ec, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock){
            if ( ec ) {
                std::cout << "accept error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                return;
            }

            boost::system::error_code wec;
            sock.wait(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::wait_read, wec);
            if ( wec ) {
                std::cout << "wait error: " << wec.message() << std::endl;
            } else {
                std::cout << "wait OK" << std::endl;
            }
        }
    );

    return ioctx.run();
}
```

Tested using boost-1.69 and boost-1.72

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `async_wait` merely waits for the socket to become ready. The docs say, specifically:

> Asynchronously wait for the socket to become ready to read, ready to write, or to have pending error conditions.

Note that the peer shutdown does NOT constitute that kind of error condition (thanks @DavidSchwartz for pointing this out in the comments).

Instead, a subsequent read operation will reveal  that condition (which in Asio is presented through the error code `asio::error::eof`).

The idea here is that you use `async_wait` for reactor-style handlers, and you would like the behaviour of the socket to be transparent for the code that uses the underlying IO handle (e.g. it could be third-party library code which want to respond to peer shutdown, so it wouldn't make sense to rob it of the opportunity by handling it on the Asio level)

Comment: I don't see where I said that. Let me see whether I can clarify my wordings. Or maybe it's just the wording of the docs (that I can't take responsibility for)?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Actually that linked issue helped my understanding of the docs: I had misread it. I didn't assume that a peer shutdown would be an error condition, but I did misread it as a promise to "complete" when the read _would_ yield an `error_code` of `boost::asio::error::eof`. It looks like the documentation doesn't explicitly deal with such cases then. It still stands to reason that any such _condition_ will be revealed on the next operation, **because** that's the only logical way in which reactor-style operations can be **transparently** supported.

Comment: No no. The OP was saying that the operation completes with zero `error_code`, which is fortunately much less of an issue :) My answer was intended to explain _why_ it is not an issue.

Comment: I think you're wrong. I’ll try to explain why I think so. if you follow the [doc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/reactor.html) for `async_wait()`/`wait()` you can see an example in which `error_code` received from `async_wait()` is checked before reading from the socket. I am sure the author of asio assumed exactly this behavior for `wait()`/`async_wait()`. If we assume you're right, then this example shows the reading from the closed socket.

Comment: [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/nonblocking/third_party_lib.cpp) example from asio doc also confirms my point.

Comment: and [this](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/nonblocking/third_party_lib.cpp) one too,

Comment: Well, the error needs to be checked because of OTHER conditions. What if the peer didn't close the socket, but **we** did (somewhere else)? That leads to `asio::error::operation_aborted` (similar with a `cancel()`-ed asynchronous operations). So, yes, you do need to check for error if you expect this kind of code.

Comment: I was explicitly explaining how reactor-style handlers are meant to be used to integrate with (third-party) code that wants to do their own socket operations. If you do asio-style reads anyways, I don't see (a) what difference there is compared to doing `async_read`/`async_write` or (b) why you'd complicate it using `async_wait`