# How does asio::ip::tcp::socket::async_wait behave?

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio, asio

I can't really understand the use described in asio documentation for `socket::async_wait`.
It says:

> Asynchronously wait for the socket to become ready to read, ready to write, or to have pending error conditions.

What does `pending error conditions` apply to? Does the error received within `async_send`/`async_receive` count?
If it does, will I receive the error twice: as an argument for `async_receive` and as an argument for `async_wait`? And in which order?

So far I thought that I would receive an error with `socket::async_wait` from the server on its shutdown, but I didn't receive anything...

Comment: Interesting question. I've ran into this before, and remember that @DavidSchwartz had linked an insightful post. Sadly those comments have disappeared. But maybe the very similar question helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59506756/85371

Comment: I've since come across the notion of SO_KEEPALIVE, which may or may not be instrumental to your solution

Comment: @sehe I've found out that one way to get if a server has been shut down is to invoke `asyn_receive` and wait for `eof`. But in that case I never receive an error with `async_wait`. I think there's something in the description, that should be taken into an account. It waits for **the socket** to have pending error conditions. It is very ambiguous but may be considered that a remote server's error conditions are not the socket's error conditions. But it is just a wild guess